# Android StudioでImage Assetを起動できない

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio Version 3.2.1を使用しています。

通常以下の手順でImage Assetを起動できると思いますが、
Image Assetの項目自体が出てこないため、起動することができません。

①Android Studio で Android アプリのプロジェクトを開きます。
②[Project] ウィンドウで [Android] ビューを選択します。
③res フォルダを選択して、[File] > [New] > [Image Asset] の順に選択します。

解決方法を教えていただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

同じバージョンですが、再現しませんでした。確認したのはWindows版です。
根本的な解決にはならないのですが、以下に代替手段があります。

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

このサイト上でImageAssetとほぼ同じ操作が行えると思います。
ライセンス等が異なる可能性があるので、その点はご注意ください。

Answer (score 0):

私の場合はShiftキーを2回押すとImage Assetが表示されました。選択するとアップデートする旨のメッセージが画面下部に表示されアップデートすると使えるようになりました。